Twitter API v2 Authentication Error: 401 Unauthorized Despite Correct Keys & Tokens
I am trying to access the Twitter API v2 both through the API directly on Postman and  Tweepy in Python on macOS, but I keep encountering a 401 Unauthorized error. Despite using what I believe to be are correct tokens my requests are not being authenticated. I have regenerated these keys multiple times and still am encountering the same error.
Tried:
import tweepy 

api_key = ""
api_secret = ""
bearer_token = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, api_key, api_secret, access_token,access_token_secret)

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Function to like a tweet
def like_tweet(tweet_id):
    try:
        client.like(tweet_id)
        print(f"Successfully liked tweet {tweet_id}")
    except tweepy.TweepyException as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

# Like the tweet with the specified ID
like_tweet(1813606495118062034)

Result:
in/python3 /Users/diyagirishkumar/twitterbot/tweepy_setup.py Error: 403 Forbidden
When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.

On Postman:
{
    "title": "Unauthorized",
    "type": "about:blank",
    "status": 401,
    "detail": "Unauthorized"
}


Because of the level of access, If you are on the free version, you can create or delete just the information of your tweets for exemple.
You can check this documentation : https://developer.x.com/en/portal/products/basic

I also found the same error , And spent a week in researching about the error , And after checking a node.js sdk I found that I was missing a User-Agent Headers;
please add this headers and try
 headers: {
        Accept: '*/*',
        Connection: 'close',
        'User-Agent': 'node-twitter/<PAKAGE_JSON_FILE_VERSION>' 
      }

